# shopify functions - variables not working with shop metafield

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I need to use variable for  tag ids and collection ids. I have created metafield on "shop"  and set the values for
Here is the doc [https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/functions/input-output/variables-queries`](https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/functions/input-output/variables-queries%60)

But unfortunately it is not picking up the variable values.

```
query RunInput(
  $selectedCollectionIds: [ID!]
  $selectedProductTags: [String!]
  )  {
  cart {
   lines {
      quantity
      merchandise {
        __typename
        ... on ProductVariant {
          id
          weight
          product {
            isGiftCard
            inAnyCollection(ids: $selectedCollectionIds)
            inCollections{
              __typename
              collectionId
              isMember
            }
            hasAnyTag(tags: $selectedProductTags) 
            hasTags(tags:$selectedProductTags){
              __typename
              hasTag
              tag
            }
          }
        }     
      }  
   }
  }
  shop{
     metafield(
      namespace: "$app:my_namespace"
      key: "my_key"
    ) {
      value
    } 
  }
}
```

According to the doc added the variable name in .toml file as well.

```
api_version = "2023-10"

[[extensions]]
handle = "my-app"
name = "t:name"
description = "t:description"
type = "function"

  [[extensions.targeting]]
  target = "purchase.validation.run"
  input_query = "src/run.graphql"
  export = "run"
   


  [extensions.input.variables]
  namespace = "$app:my_namespace"
  key = "my_key"


  [extensions.build]
  command = ""
  path = "dist/function.wasm"

  [extensions.ui.paths]
  create = "/"
  details = "/"
```

Here is the metafield value that was created on shop resource

```
 {
  id: 35171720954165,
  namespace: 
  '$app:my_namespace',
  key: 'my_key',
  value: '{"selectedProductTags":[],"selectedCollectionIds":["gid://shopify/Collection/442796769589","gid://shopify/Collection/442796704053","gid://shopify/Collection/442796802357"]}',
  description: null,
  owner_id: shopId,
  created_at: '2023-10-16T00:59:56-04:00',     
  updated_at: '2023-10-16T03:31:01-04:00',     
  owner_resource: 'shop',
   type: 'json',
   admin_graphql_api_id: 
  'gid://shopify/Metafield/3517172095416
  }
```

Comment: Can you try with "[input.variables]" instead of "[extensions.input.variables]" ?